# Show: $\mathbb{C}=\overline{\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I have to show that

> > $\mathbb{C}=\overline{\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}}$,

what is very probably an easy task; nevertheless I have some problems.

In words this means: $\mathbb{C}$ is the smallest closed superset of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$.

Comment: Some problems? What problems?

Comment: What do you know about point-set topology? Do you know that it suffices to exhibit $0$ as a limit point of $\mathbb C\backslash \{0\}$?

Comment: This is a valid mathematical question that has a specific answer. Closing it as off-topic is just wrong.

Comment: I have no idea why this is getting closed. That's absurd.

Comment: If the topology of $\mathbb{C}$ is given by defining the Kuratowski closure operator, then this is true by definition. In a question like this, to get a precise proof, it might be good to also provide the definition of the topology you are using.

Answer (score 6):

The elements of the sequence of complex numbers $1$, $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{3}$,$\cdots$ are all contained in $\overline{\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \} }$ but the limit of the sequence is $0$; hence $0$ is in the closure.

Comment: I see but why is that enough why follows then that $\mathbb{C}$ is the closure?

Comment: The distance from $0$ to $\frac{1}{n}$ is $\frac{1}{n}$ and this distance goes to $0$ and $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Hm, I don't know if you got my problem or if I asked wrong... I know, that the closure consists of the limits of all convergent nets (especially all convergent sequences) with elements in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$. Now, your sequence is in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ and converges to 0, so $0\in\overline{\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}}$. But why follows from this, that $\mathbb{C}=\overline{\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}}$. Thats not clear to me. Sorry.

Comment: The closure of a set contains all the limit points.

Comment: Hm, I guess I am blind then... i understand that it contains 0... but why $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$, too in order to get $\mathbb{C}$ as the closure??

Comment: In your question you are asking about the closure of the set $\mathbb{C} \setminus {0}$. That is why the elements in the sequence need to be in $\mathbb{C} \setminus {0}$.

Comment: Yes that is cleat to me! Oh, I dont know how to formulate my question.. you do not get my problem (maybe very stupid problem). 0 is in the closure. And the closure contains all limits of convergent nets in $C\setminus 0$. All clear. But I still do not see that then C has to be the searched closure.

Comment: @math12 The closure of $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ must contain the set $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ by definition. It also contains $0$ by the argument above. Hence it's the entire space $\mathbb C$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, i guess. One has showm, that 0 is in the closure and per definitionem $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ is in the closure, too. Now it is $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}\subset \mathbb{C}=\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}\cup\left\{0\right\}$ and so $\mathbb{C}$ is the smallest closed set containing $\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: (I assume you're using the usual topology on $\Bbb C$.) Note that $\{0\}$ is not an open set, so $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ is not a closed set. $\Bbb C$ is closed, however. Is $\Bbb C$ a superset of $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$? If so, how many extra points does it have? What can you conclude?

Answer (score 1):

${\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}}$ is open, $\mathbb{C}$ is closed, and since $\overline{\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}}$ is the smallest closed set containing ${\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}}$, it must be equal to $\mathbb{C}$ (since the only set containing but not equal to ${\mathbb{C}\setminus\left\{0\right\}}$ is $\mathbb{C}$).

Answer (score 0):

$\partial(\mathbf{C}^\ast)$ consists of $0$ alone, use $\overline{\mathbf{C}^\ast}=\partial(\mathbf{C}^\ast)\cup\mathbf{C}^\ast$.